# MongoDB Database is not created in Kotlin(Ktor)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kmongo

please i need help with connecting a mongodb to my ktor application.
This is the code i have, as followed from this article: https://himanshoe.com/mongodb-in-ktor

```
class MongoDataHandler {

val client = KMongo.createClient().coroutine
val database = client.getDatabase("dev")
val userCollection = database.getCollection<User>()

suspend fun adduser(email: String, username: String, password: String): User? {
userCollection.insertOne(User(userId = null, email = email, userName = username, passwordHash = password))
return userCollection.findOne(User::email eq email )
}
suspend fun finduser(id: String): User?{
return userCollection.findOneById(id)
}
}
```

I installed mongodb as directed from their website. The mongodb is started as a service upon successful install. I run this command  "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\mongo.exe" to use the mongodb. When i check for the available database using "show dbs", i realize that my database(dev) is not listed.
This is the dependency am using:

```
implementation("org.litote.kmongo:kmongo-coroutine:4.2.8")
```

And this the the error i am getting:

```
[eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] INFO  Application - 500 Internal Server Error: 
POST - /user
```

I guess i am doing something wrong... thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to connect to a MongoDB database without the Ktor? If so, please share a code for a complete project.

Comment: Yes, i am able to connect to mongodb without Ktor. Here is a link to the project.. https://github.com/Toluxpersia/Link.. Thnks

Comment: If I pass environment variables `JWT_SECRET` and `SECRET_KEY` while running your application with valid values, then `java.lang.IllegalStateException: generation for id property type not supported : class kotlin.Int` is thrown in the `adduser` method.

Comment: Also, please make sure you send a request with `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Can you try using a String variable for the JWT_SCRETE and SECRET_KEY constants? and i use Postman to make requests appropriately. But ultimately, am i creating and initializing the database correctly?

Comment: I use random strings for those environment variables. I believe you do it correctly.

Comment: I found another solution using docker compose...thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your MongoDataHandler to the following, using the  `MongoClients.create()` method, and adding a codecRegistry to your client.

You will not need the connection string settings if you are using the local connection with the default settings:

```
class MongoDataHandler {
    private val database: MongoDatabase
    private val usersCollection: MongoCollection<User>

    init {
        val pojoCodecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromProviders(
            PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                .automatic(true)
                .build()
        )

        val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry)
        val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
//            .applyConnectionString("localhost") => add the connection string if not using localhost
            .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
            .build()

        val mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings)
        database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dev")
        usersCollection = database.getCollection(User::class.java.name, User::class.java)

    }
```

Also, if you are not using docker, try to use docker-compose to orchestrate your mongodb container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

If you want a running example with Ktor/MongoDB take a look in this [project](https://github.com/coderade/ktor-mongodb-sample)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in development mode and trying this in our local machine.

Make sure you have MongoDB installed on the local machine and the local server is running well. [Here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04/) is a guide for ubuntu.

After successful setup and installation of MongoDB, run this command
`mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'`

The output should contain a line as below:
`connecting to : mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb`

Make sure to add this line while creating client in the `ConnectionString` like:\

```
private val client = KMongo.createClient(
    ConnectionString("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
).coroutine
```

Then try working on your requests/operations with the Ktor, it should work fine.